# Export storedprocedure(SQL Server 2008 r2) data to excel 2010(more than 255 columns) using ssis 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, excel-2010, export-to-excel, ssis-2008

I want to export output of a stored-procedure(SQL Server 2008 r2)  to excel 2010 file(.xlsx) using SSIS 2008. The output of the stored-procedure generates more than 255 columns (e.g. 300 columns). When I use excel destination in SSIS 2008 I see only 255 columns are visible for mapping. Please let me know how to fix this issue. Also you can suggest any feasible option to achieve this. - Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest that if you are exporting 255 columns, this is not for human analysis and consumption, it's just a feed to another system or report. Is that correct?

Comment: I think Excel has a limitation on the number of columns (which is 255). Maybe you want to split the feed evenly on 2 sheets instead of a single sheet?